# Finding matrix $A(2\times3)$, given kernel and certain other conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The conditions:
$$
\{x\in\mathbb Z_7^3: f_A(x)=0\} = \{t(3,2,5)^T: t\in\mathbb Z_7\} \\
\{f_A(x): x\in\mathbb Z_7^3\}=\{t(1,3)^T: t\in\mathbb Z_7\}
$$

hello, this assignment is in one of our books and i have trouble figuring out what to do about it. we have only scratched the surface of the topics like null space, kernel etc.

if i understand the problem correctly, than

- the matrix times the transposed vector $(3,2,5)t$ should equal $(0,0)$.
- the second condition tells us that the matrix times whatever $(x,y,z)$ should equal to the transposed vector $(1,3)t$.

i really dont know how to put the two pieces of information together. i have spent hours on the problem and really cant get anywhere. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: we are supposed to find all matrices A which meet the conditions.

Comment: Did you try to find all matrices meeting the first condition ? If $A=(a_{ij})$, then $3a_{11}+2a_{12}+5a_{13}=0$ and $3a_{21}+2a_{22}+5a_{23}=0$ are the equations you need to solve over $\mathbb{F}_7$. There are not many possibilities.

Comment: Have you learned how to find the image and kernel (nullspace) of a matrix via row- and column-reduction?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the second condition, which says that $\operatorname{im}f$ is spanned by $(1,3)^T$. This tells us that the second row of $A$ is equal to $3$ times the first, i.e., that $A$ is of the form $$\pmatrix{a&b&c\\3a&3b&3c}.$$ The first condition says that $(3,2,5)^T\in\ker A$. (It actually says more, but this is all we need for now). Multiplying this vector by $A$ and setting the result equal to zero yields the equation $3a+2b+5c=0$, as noted in Dietrich Burde’s comment above, or $a=3(c-b)$ when solved over $\mathbb Z_7$. Putting this together, we find that $$
A=\pmatrix{
3(c-b) & b & c \\
2(c-b) & 3b & 3c
}.
$$ This may be too many solutions, though. The first condition says that $\ker A$ is *exactly* $\operatorname{span}\{(3,2,5)^T\}$, so some of the matrices that have the form above might need to be culled from the solution set. By the rank-nullity theorem, which also holds for vector spaces over finite fields, the kernel ought to be two-dimensional, though, so perhaps the first condition is misstated.